# SQL query result within IN

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT ids_horarios_adicionales from adicionales WHERE id_adicionales=1
```

So this query returns as result `1,3`, the row `ids_horarios_adicionales` will contain ids separated with commas.

What im intending to do is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM adicionales a
LEFT JOIN horarios b ON b.id_horarios IN (1,3)
WHERE id_adicionales=1
```

but when I use this query, results are not the same:

```
SELECT *
FROM adicionales a
LEFT JOIN horarios b ON b.id_horarios IN (SELECT ids_horarios_adicionales from adicionales WHERE id_adicionales=1)
WHERE id_adicionales=1
```

any idea how to make SELECT query inside IN() to print as `1,3`

This is the schema and sql query result I want, any other approach sugested will be helpful: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/714a50/2

Comment: The best idea is to normalize your databale and store `1` and `3` as stomic values in separate rows of table, but not a string `1,3` (three characters). If yoy don't like this idea, then you must firt parse this string and split it into individual values. Look for `mysql split comma separated list` on SO, there are plenty of answers on this topic.

Comment: @krokodilko this is the result I want, what approach do u suggest? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/714a50/2

Comment: This seems like a really strange way to structure the query.  Your question should include sample data and desired results (it is nice to have the SQL Fiddle, but the base question should have it too).

Answer (score 1):

You should not be storing values in a comma-separated list.  That is the problem you are facing.  I would recommend figuring out how to change your data structure.

But, sometimes, you are stuck with other people's really bad designs (such as storing integer values in strings).  In that case, you can use `find_in_set()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM adicionales a LEFT JOIN
     horarios h
     ON EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM adicionales a2 
                WHERE find_in_set(h.id_horarios , a2) > 0 AND 
                      a2.id_adicionales = 1
               )
WHERE id_adicionales = 1
```

Comment: Unknown column 'a2' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1):

you can use FIND_IN_SET by this way

```
SELECT *
FROM adicionales a
LEFT JOIN horarios b ON 
FIND_IN_SET(a.ids_horarios_adicionales,b.id_horarios)
WHERE id_adicionales=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your schema but in general when using LEFT JOIN you need to detail how the join between the tables us done.  For example, LEFT JOIN  horarios b ON b.index = adicionales.index and then use the where statement to limit rows

Comment: this is what I intend http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/714a50/2 , any suggestion ?

Comment: Should be like this:
SELECT * FROM adicionales a LEFT JOIN horarios b ON b.id_horarios = a.id_adicionales WHERE a.id_adicionales=1